# "Read Analog Voltage" sample rate

Tags: arduino, sample-rate, analog-digital-converter

In this arduino example:

[ReadAnalogVoltage](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadAnalogVoltage)

What would the samplerate be if I run it on a MEGA 2560?
And what should I do to set the samplerate to 6kHz?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should add `delay(166)`, that would be something around 6.024Hz. But also floating point is super slow on Arduinos, so it might get slower than that. And also one millisecond in Arduino is not 1000us but 1024us, so it might be even less than 6Hz.

The best way is setting up one timer to auto trigger `ADC` and use `ADIF` (AD Interrupt Flag) to read value from `ADC` register pair, clear the flag, do the math and wait for another reading. But this is the hard way for a newbie.

Edit: For 6kHz it would be much more auto trigger mode and values in `mV` as an integer. Floating point arithmetics is extremely slow as it's just emulated by software.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I ruined my question. I will just try to ask it here again.

Comment: @AprilDC Well then auto trigger mode is far more reliable. Plus not using floats!